# Generating msg files from asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a simple page with a button / link on it.

When the user clicks on the link, the application should generate the .msg file which contains subject, send to address, and file attachment. The user should be able to automatically download the generated file, open it in Outlook, and make necessary changes before sending the file.

I don't want to send the email from the server side because every user has its own signature. Mailto protocol doesn't allow attachments so I'm guessing that creating an email message as a .msg file and sending it to a response stream is the easiest thing to do.

Is there any .net library for creating .msg files which doesn't require the Outlook to be installed on the server? Aspose.Email is a bit pricey for us.

Comment: I could be missing it, but what's the role of the server-side stuff in this use case if at the end of the day, it will be Outlook where whatever was done on the server side can be modified by user?

Comment: @EdSF, server side stuff will prepare the template, attach documents, fill in email addresses, etc. It will save the end user a lot of time.

Comment: Understood. IMHO, that could all be done server side (your original approach). Also unsure about what you meant by "doesn't allow attachments". In any case, I believe you got your answer below. Best ~

Comment: I know this is probably way too late, but I found msgkit to work very well. https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not generate an EML file (which is text)?

Comment: Can I save EML file as draft?

Comment: I can set it as a draft by setting 'X-Unsent = 1' in the header.